# paramter estimation (maximum likelihood) of a mixture density

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

I have this mixture distribution

$f(x) =w \cdot \mathcal{LN}(\mu_1,\sigma) + (1-w)\cdot \mathcal{LN}(\mu_2,\sigma) $

where $\mathcal{LN}(\mu,\sigma)$ is a lognormal distribution.

I now have random variables

$ Y = \sum_{i=0}^n X_i $ where all $X_i$ are distributed according to $f(x)$.

How can I get the maximum likelihood estimation for the unknown paramters $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and $\sigma$ (w is given)? We can also assume that $n$ is a small number, for example $n=10$.

Are there other methods of finding the parameters?

Comment: May be better suited to: stats.stackexchange.com /// perhaps some EM method ...

Comment: Suppose $X_i$ has density $f$. Then $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ has density $f*f*\cdots*f$, where $*$ is the convolution operator. Thus, the density of $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is also parameterized by $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and such parameterization is known. MLE can then be carried out.